# grade 10 (state the equation of a line) question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is : state the equation of the line that is parallel to the line defined by y=7 that passes through (-4,-6).

I didn't understand this question!!

Comment: The wording used in the question is suboptimal. What is intended is something like "state the equation of the line that passes through $(-4,-6)$ and is parallel to the line with equation $y=7$." I don't like "the" equation either, since a line has many equations. But I am being too fussy there.

Answer (score 1):

First, what does $y=7$ look like? Plot some points whose $y$-coordinate is $7$ to get an idea, maybe $(0,7)$, $(1,7)$, $(100,7)$, $(-23,7)$.

Now that you know what $y=7$ looks like, look at the point in the question, $(-4,-6)$. You want to draw another line that is [parallel](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Two_Parallel_lines.svg/330px-Two_Parallel_lines.svg.png) (think train tracks) to your first line, but goes through $(-4,-6)$. Draw what you think it should be, and think about what the equation for that line will be. Hint: it will look similar to the equation of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

The line $y=7$ is parallel to the $x$-axis. Notice how $x$ does not appear in the equation $y=7$. This means that for any value of $x$, the value of $y$ is 7. So it's a flat line.

Now, any line parallel to this one will also be a flat line.

If the value of the new line at $x=-4$ is $y=-6$, and the line is flat, what must the value of $y$ be at any other value of $x$?

Answer (score 0):

The line defined by $y=7$ is a horizontal line. Any other horizontal line will be paralel to it, so the line you are looking for will be defined as $y=C$ for some $C$. Since it will pass through $(-4,-6)$, it's easy to determine $C$.